# How to update mongoDB from python, even if python script handling the process is stopped manually/forcefully?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am doing some processing on data which after processing is then stored in mongoDB collection. For this I have maintained two versions i.e. collections of processed data which are `LEVEL_TWO_CLEANED_DATA_V1` and `LEVEL_TWO_CLEANED_DATA_V2`.

If I am using one version for processing and some other application need to access the processed data, then another version is still available to use. I am maintaining all the information required to check which version is active in another collection, called `VERSION_METADATA_LEVEL_TWO`. The sample documents in this collection look like:

```
> db.VERSION_METADATA_LEVEL_TWO.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : "V1",
        "COLLECTION_NAME" : "LEVEL_TWO_CLEANED_DATA_V1",
        "DELTA" : 21,
        "LAST_ACTIVE_TIME" : ISODate("2018-04-06T11:56:48.020Z"),
        "PROCESSING_STATUS" : "COMPLETE",
        "STATUS" : "ACTIVE"
}
{
        "_id" : "V2",
        "COLLECTION_NAME" : "LEVEL_TWO_CLEANED_DATA_V2",
        "DELTA" : 18,
        "LAST_ACTIVE_TIME" : ISODate("2018-04-06T10:51:03.029Z"),
        "PROCESSING_STATUS" : "IN_PROGRESS",
        "STATUS" : "INACTIVE"
}
```

I am trying to implement it in a way that even if python script handling the processing is forcefully closed, the `VERSION_METADATA_LEVEL_TWO` collection can be updated to notify failed processing i.e. it should show `"PROCESSING_STATUS" : "FAILED"` in particular collection. I tried using try:except in python:

```
try:
    LevelTwoCleanser.initaialize()
except Exception as e:
    MongoDatabase.updateProcessingStatusForMetadataCollectionLevelTwo(DataFormatter.INACTIVE_COLLECTION_LEVEL_TWO, "FAILED")
```

But, it didn't worked. Is there any way of doing it in python?

Comment: what do you mean by _forcefully closed_?

Comment: terminating the execution of script

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch event when user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you should add exception handling for `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Also `systemd` or IDE like eclipse can send `SIGTERM` OS signal to your process, so in order to intercept this signal you should add a separate handler for it.

```
import signal
import sys


def sigterm_handler(signal, frame):
    # SIGTERM received
    MongoDatabase.updateProcessingStatusForMetadataCollectionLevelTwo(DataFormatter.INACTIVE_COLLECTION_LEVEL_TWO, "FAILED")
    # do cleanup - close DB connections, save data, etc.
    sys.exit(0)  # stop the app


# you should probably put the following line in the startup section of your app
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)

try:  # do something
    LevelTwoCleanser.initaialize()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
    # user pressed ctrl+C or processing failed or there is a DB error or any kind of python error
    MongoDatabase.updateProcessingStatusForMetadataCollectionLevelTwo(DataFormatter.INACTIVE_COLLECTION_LEVEL_TWO, "FAILED")
```

---

But remember - there are some cases, that you cannot detect or intercept. For example if someone turns off your computer, or if user or OS sends `SIGKILL` signal which immediately stops your app and cannot be caught or ignored by your process.

Some utilities first send `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` signal and waits until app does some cleanup. Then, if target process does not stop after some amount of time, it sends `SIGKILL`.

Comment: It didn't worked. Does it matter from where I terminate the script as I am terminating it in Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe. How do you terminate your script?

Comment: By clicking the red button in eclipse console.

Comment: Eclipse is not relevant, it's just an IDE. How will you terminate script in production environment?

Comment: In production, it may get terminated by factors like system failure, because of some bugs or other factors that can stop the application unexpectedly by creating some deadlocks or anything like that.

Comment: added some information and explanation to the answer